# Gaussian process classification with R kernlab package: issue predicting test set larger than training set

Tags: r, kernlab

I'm using `gausspr` function from the `kernlab` package for Gaussian process classification, and running into the following error message:

> Error in votematrix[i, ret > 0] : (subscript) logical subscript too
>   long

anytime I try to use the classifier to make predictions on a dataset that has more observations than the training set.
Here's a very simple example to reproduce this problem:

```
data(iris)
gp1 = gausspr(Species ~., data=iris)
predict(gp1,iris[c(1:150,1),-5])
```

Has anyone else run into this problem?  Any insights into how to get around it other than calling predict many times on smaller subsets of the test data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to review the code right now, but predicting `'probabilities'` jumps the faulty code, so try this instead:

```r
data(iris)
gp1 = gausspr(Species ~., data=iris)
predict(gp1,iris[c(1:150,1),-5], type = 'probabilities')
```

And work with the probabilities.

---

[This is the loop that outputs that error if you want to review it.](https://github.com/cran/kernlab/blob/master/R/gausspr.R#L355)